# Application_Error handler isn't fired when use prefix async

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have to make an asynchronous call in Application_Error handler. So I've defined this handler with async keyword but it isn't fired on exceptions.

```
    protected async void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        await DoAsyncCall();

        ...
    }
```

The handler is fired when I remove async keyword.

BTW, I've tired to add async keyword to Application_Start handler and it works fine.

How can I make Application_Error async? Or how can I make asynchronous calls without async keyword?

Comment: `async` doesn make callsrun asynchronously. It tells the compiler to put special code to `await` for markes asynchronsous calls to complete. Unless DoAsyncCall is already asynchronous, it will execute synchronously. Your Application_Start method probably executes synchronously, unless you make an async call to some service or use Task.Run

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found the solution:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    Task task = Task.Run(async () => await DoAsyncCall());

    task.Wait();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why are you using async and then block?

Comment: OK, let me explain. I have a library that works with external API. Library communicates with API via HttpClient (PostAsync method). I'm using this library at every page in my web application. I'm doing these calls by registering PageAsyncTask and it works fine. But I also need to do some call in case of application error. And because I cannon use PageAsyncTask in Global.aspx I have to use the solution above. DoAsyncCall() here is just for example (instead I have: await service.UpdateOrderStatusAsync(...).

Comment: `Task` implements `IAsyncResult`. You could use one of the `AddOn<event>Async` but you don't have one for `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you posted uses Task.Run. What I think this means is that you will have one thread waiting for the async task to run and a second thread executing the task. This may mean that you end up using two threads.

I had a similar question but answered it by using the Server.TransferRequest function to initiate a new async request. I then did all the processing in the following request. By passing all the data via the header parameter of TransferRequest, I had an async error controller using only one thread. See [Asynchronous error controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584427/asynchronous-error-controller-in-asp-net-mvc/27586322#27586322).

Hope this helps other people with this issue.