# Asynchronous error controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, error-handling

Can anyone help me get an asynchronous error controller working in ASP MVC. I have it all working without it being asynchronous but that does not seem right. The code I started with is below:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        // A good location for any error logging, otherwise, do it inside of the error controller.

        // Clear the error, otherwise, we will always get the default error page.
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        var code = (exception is HttpException) ? (exception as HttpException).GetHttpCode() : 500;

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "index");
        IController errorController = ClassFactory.Resolve<ErrorController>();
        errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

And the method signature for my error controller is as follows:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(int code = 500)
    {
```

If I make the error controller method async, the Execute method in Application_Error throws the exception "The asynchronous action method 'index' returns a Task, which cannot be executed synchronously."

One of my most promising attempts was transferring the request. This used the following code in the applicaiton_error method:

```
var code = (exception is HttpException) ? (exception as HttpException).GetHttpCode() : 500;
var headers = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"ErrorUrl", Context.Request.RawUrl},
    {"ErrorCode", code.ToString()}
};
Context.Server.TransferRequest("~/error", false, null, headers, true);
```

This worked well and async, and I could pass the error data in the request headers. Unfortunately the Server.TransferRequest call lost details about the current logged in user and the user would appear on the error page as being logged out. The user login code is currently identical to that of the VS2013 templates (not the old forms auth). The preserveUser parameter does not seem to work.

**Has anyone got such an asynchronous controller working?**

OR

**Does anyone know how to solve the ASP Identity being lost on TransferRequest?**

Related questions include [Application_Error handler isn't fired when use prefix async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20376682/application-error-handler-isnt-fired-when-use-prefix-async) which has a solution worse than not using async (using two threads at once). Also another ananswered question [similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012088/mvc4-error-the-asynchronous-action-method-cannot-be-executed-synchronously) but without the TransferRequest.

Comment: Can you post your controller method? May be it can be made not `async` at all

Comment: I can get the controller working without async, but it would be better to have everything async. The error controller needs DB access to suggest possible pages and potentially redirect the user to the correct page.

Comment: If controller does nothing but show the view it shouldn't be async. Async is for i/o operations

Comment: I mentioned in the comment above that the error controller needs DB access. This is needed to retrieve the data for the view and/or which page to redirect to. Database access is a perfect example of where async operations are very useful.

Comment: I might have missed that, then cool that you've found a solution!

Comment: That is ok, still a valid point for some viewers. I think error pages in generally need to be very data focused. If I go to a page such as amazon.com/buy/kindle, it is a 404 page with nothing but a link to the home page. If they picked up on the word 'kindle' in the url, they could include links to kindles on their 404 page and gain another customer.

Answer (score 5):

Context.Server.TransferRequest was the correct way to solve the problem. This function sends the following request through the entire IIS pipeline. The reason I was loosing the ASP Identity is that it is stored in the Session. The session is linked to the client using cookies. Cookies are in the header.

Instead of the code:

```
var code = (exception is HttpException) ? (exception as HttpException).GetHttpCode() : 500;
var headers = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"ErrorUrl", Context.Request.RawUrl},
    {"ErrorCode", code.ToString()}
};
Context.Server.TransferRequest("~/error", false, null, headers, true);
```

I have got it working with:

```
var code = (exception is HttpException) ? (exception as HttpException).GetHttpCode() : 500;
var headers = Request.Headers;
headers.Add(new NameValueCollection
{
    {"ErrorUrl", Context.Request.RawUrl},
    {"ErrorCode", code.ToString()}
});
Context.Server.TransferRequest("~/error", false, null, headers, true);
```

The main difference is that I am passing in the headers of the current request, which contain the cookies, which link to the session. This stops the ASP.NET identity from being lost.

Comment: The second param is `preserveForm` which was useful to set to true in my case - worth watching out for